# The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements

Tags: trigger.io

This is specific to Trigger.io.

When trying to upload my application through Application Loader, I am getting the error: "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate."

I'm very certain, I'm using the correct certificate (i.e. the distribution one, and not the development one). Actually, I'm 100% sure I'm using the right certificate.

That leaves me with signature was invalid or contains disallowed entitlements.

Has anyone encountered this while trying to upload an IPA created through Trigger.io?

I have the latest Xcode & Xcode command line tools on my machine. I am getting this error when I create builds on both Windows and Mac OS.

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: While I love Trigger.io, I'm about ready to abandon it due to the hassles I'm running into trying to upload my app.

Answer (score 3):

I think the root cause here was that I was using an incorrect version of XCode (and Application Loader), that had me trashing with provisioning profiles, App Ids, and certificates.

Via the iOS Provisioning Portal, I ensured that the distribution provisioning profile was active, I was using a non-wildcard App ID, and that the distribution certificate was active. Once I cleaned house, and recreated everything, it finally worked.

I do think that I only saw this problem because I was using the wrong version of XCode and Application Loader.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when accidentally archiving using an iPhone Developer code signing identity, instead of using iPhone Distribution.

I.e. exactly as the message says, I did not use a distrib cert.